# Is there a way to use a string text as the input of a method in python?

Tags: python

I have a method, which takes a lot arguments as input.
Something like this, but with more args:

```
foo.add(a=True, b=0, c='z', d=(1, 0, 0), e=2, f='g')
foo.add(a=False, b=3, c='z', d=(1, 0, 2), e=2, f='z')
foo.add(a=True, b=10, c='h', d=(1, 3, 0), e=2, f='2')
```

I decided to make a dictionary and add each line's args into that. But I can not use it like this:

```
foo_dict = {
    "a": "a=True, b=0, c='z', d=(1, 0, 0), e=2, f='g'",
    "b": "a=False, b=3, c='z', d=(1, 0, 2), e=2, f='z'",
    "c": "a=True, b=10, c='h', d=(1, 3, 0), e=2, f='2'",
}
foo.add(foo_dict["a"])
foo.add(foo_dict["b"])
foo.add(foo_dict["c"])
```

What is the best way to pass the args from another variable and not getting error?

Comment: Close.  If the inner strings were a `dict`, you could use a double splat (unpacking). `foo.add(**foo_dict["a"])`

Comment: See [Python args and kwargs: Demystified](https://realpython.com/python-kwargs-and-args/).

Answer (score 1):

Make each value a `dict`, then you can unpack it with `**`.

```py
foo_dict = {
    "a": {'a':True, 'b':0, 'c':'z', 'd':(1, 0, 0), 'e':2, 'f':'g'},
    "b": {'a':False, 'b':3, 'c':'z', 'd':(1, 0, 2), 'e':2, 'f':'z'},
    "c": {'a':True, 'b':10, 'c':'h', 'd':(1, 3, 0), 'e':2, 'f':'2'},
}
for v in foo_dict.values():
    foo.add(**v)
```